# More on Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm not sure how to even begin this problem:

Find the matrix for a linear transformation that takes the x-axis to the line $y=3x$ and takes the y-axis to the line $y=6x$.

Comment: It takes $(0,y)^{T}$ to $(\frac{y}{6},y)^{T}$ and takes $(x,0)^{T}$ to $(x,3x)^{T}$. Now let $A$ be matrix representing this transform, and write down above conditions in equations in terms of matrix coefficients

Comment: Alternatively, the columns of a matrix representing a linear transformation are exactly where the basis vectors are sent by that linear transformation. So $(1,0)^T$ is sent to, for instance, $(3,1)^T$, which means that $(3,1)^T$ is the first column of $A$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Linear Algebra.  What does the $T$ in $(0,y)^T$ mean?